# Integrating $\int \left( \frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta} \right)^n \, d\theta$, for $n=2$ and $n=3$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

How do you integrate the following functions:
$$\int \left( \frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta} \right)^2 \, d\theta$$ and $$\int \left( \frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta} \right)^3 \, d\theta 
$$
respectively?

**Note:** Initially, I tried integrating the function without the power and obtained the result below. 
$$
\int \frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta} \, d\theta = \arctan(\sin\theta)+ C
$$
However, from here it is difficult to proceed. Integration by substitution doesn't seem to work.

How should I go on from here? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

See question [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx).

The *universal standard substitution* to evaluate an integral of a rational fraction in $\sin \theta,\cos \theta$, i.e. a rational fraction of the form

$$R(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)=\frac{P(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)}{Q(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)},$$

where $P,Q$  are polynomials in $\sin \theta,\cos \theta$ is a trigonometric substitution known as the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)

$$
\begin{equation*}
\tan \frac{\theta }{2}=t,\qquad\theta =2\arctan t,\qquad d\theta =\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}dt
\end{equation*},
$$

which converts the integrand into a rational function in $t$. We know from trigonometry (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/377139/752)) that

$$\cos \theta =\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{
\theta}{2}}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\qquad \sin \theta =\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}
\frac{\theta }{2}}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$

Applying this substitution to e.g. the first integral, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \left( \frac{\cos \theta }{1+\sin ^{2}\theta }\right) ^{2}d\theta
=\int \left( \frac{\cos \theta }{2-\cos ^{2}\theta }\right) ^{2}d\theta  \\
&=&\int \frac{2\left( 1+t^{2}\right) \left( t^{2}-1\right) ^{2}}{\left(
1+6t^{2}+t^{4}\right) ^{2}}dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

*[Edited and added.]* The integrand can be expanded as
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2\left( 1+t^{2}\right) \left( t^{2}-1\right) ^{2}}{\left(
1+6t^{2}+t^{4}\right) ^{2}} &=&\frac{16+80t^{2}}{\left(
1+6t^{2}+t^{4}\right) ^{2}}+\frac{2t^{2}-14}{1+6t^{2}+t^{4}} \\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\frac{4-3\sqrt{2}}{t^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{5\sqrt{2}-7}{
\left( t^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}}\\&+&\frac{1}{4}\frac{4+3\sqrt{2}}{t^{2}+3+2
\sqrt{2}}-\frac{7+5\sqrt{2}}{\left( t^{2}+3+2\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

With the help of SWP I evaluated
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{4}\frac{4\mp 3\sqrt{2}}{t^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}}dt &=&\frac{1}{4}
\frac{4\pm 3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}-1}, \\
\int \frac{-7+5\sqrt{2}}{\left( t^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}}dt &=&\frac{
(7-5\sqrt{2})t}{2\left( -3+2\sqrt{2}\right) \left( t^{2}+3-2\sqrt{2}\right) }\\
&+&\frac{7-5\sqrt{2}}{2\left( -3+2\sqrt{2}\right) \left( \sqrt{2}-1\right) }
\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}-1}, \\
-\int \frac{7+5\sqrt{2}}{\left( t^{2}+3+2\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}}dt &=&-\frac{
(7+5\sqrt{2})t}{2\left( 3+2\sqrt{2}\right) \left( t^{2}+3+2\sqrt{2}\right) }\\&-&
\frac{7+5\sqrt{2}}{2\left( 3+2\sqrt{2}\right) \left( \sqrt{2}+1\right) }
\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

As a consequence the integral $I$ can be written as
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\frac{1}{4}\frac{-10+7\sqrt{2}}{-5\sqrt{2}+7}\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}-1}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{10+7\sqrt{2}}{7+5\sqrt{2}}\arctan \frac{t}{\sqrt{2}+1}\\&-&\frac{t^{3}-t}{t^{4}+6t^{2}+1}+C, \\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\frac{-10+7\sqrt{2}}{-5\sqrt{2}+7}\arctan \frac{\tan \frac{
\theta }{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{10+7\sqrt{2}}{7+5\sqrt{2}}\arctan 
\frac{\tan \frac{\theta }{2}}{\sqrt{2}+1}\\&-&\frac{ \tan ^{3}\frac{\theta }{2}
-\tan \frac{\theta }{2}}{ \tan^{4} \frac{\theta }{2}
+6 \tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2} +1}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. However, at the final part, how do you expand the partial fractions?

Comment: @quest326 I made the substitution $X=t^2$ to reduce the degree of the numerator and denominator. I got $$\frac{2\left( 1+X\right) \left( X-1\right) ^{2}}{\left( 1+6X+X^{2}\right)
^{2}}=\frac{16+80X}{\left( 1+6X+X^{2}\right) ^{2}}+\frac{2X-14}{1+6X+X^{2}}.$$ I didn't proceed but we may factor the denominators  $$1+6t^2+t^4=(t^2+3-2\sqrt{2})(t^2+3+2\sqrt{2}).$$ Anyhow the  fractions are not easily integrable.

Answer (score 3):

The latter integral may be done by substituting $\tan{\phi} = \sin{\theta}$; the result is the integral

$$\int d\theta \left ( \frac{\cos{\theta}}{1+\sin^2{\theta}}\right)^3 = \int d\phi\, (\cos^4{\phi}-\cos^2{\phi} \sin^2{\phi})$$

which I trust is an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \begin{align*} \int \frac{\cos^2 x}{\left(1 + \sin^2 x\right)^2} \ dx &= \int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\left(\sec^2 x + \tan^2 x\right)^2} \ dx \\ &= \int \frac{1}{\left(2\tan^2x + 1\right)^2}\ d(\tan x) \\ \left(\tan x \mapsto \frac{\tan u}{\sqrt2} \right) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{\sec^2 u}{\sec^4 u} \ du \\&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int\cos(2u) + 1 \ du \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\sin(2u)}{2} + u \right) + C \\ &=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\sin(2\arctan(\sqrt2\tan x))}{2} + \arctan\left(\sqrt{2}\tan x\right)\right)+C\\&= \frac{\tan x}{2\left(2\tan^2x + 1\right)} + \frac{\arctan(\sqrt2 \tan x)}{2\sqrt{2}} + C\end{align*}$$

Comment: +1, very nice. Minor typo: the exponent $2$ is missing in the denominator of the 2nd. integral.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will be solving the first integral. If I can figure out the second integral I'll post my solution as another answer.
$$I=\int\bigg(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin^2x}\bigg)^2\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int\frac{\cos^2x}{(1+\sin^2x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int\frac{\sec^2 x\ \mathrm{d}x}{(2\tan^2x+1)^2}$$
$t=\tan x\Rightarrow \mathrm{d}t=\sec^2x\ \mathrm{d}x$:
$$I=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(2t^2+1)^2}$$
Apply the reduction formula
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(ax^2+b)^n}=\frac{x}{2b(n-1)(ax^2+b)^2}+\frac{2n-3}{2b(n-1)}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(ax^2+b)^{n-1}}$$
With $a=2,\ b=1,\ n=2$:
$$I=\frac{t}{2(2t^2+1)}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2t^2+1}$$
Preform $u=\sqrt{2}\ t$: 
$$I=\frac{t}{2(2t^2+1)}+\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}$$
$$I=\frac{t}{2(2t^2+1)}+\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\arctan u$$
$$I=\frac{t}{2(2t^2+1)}+\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\arctan t\sqrt{2}$$
$$I=\frac{\tan x}{2(2\tan^2x+1)}+\frac1{2\sqrt{2}}\arctan(\sqrt{2}\tan x)\quad +C$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $\sec^2 \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2=&\int\left(\frac{\cos \theta}{1+\sin ^{2} \theta}\right)^{2} d \theta\\=& \int \frac{\sec ^{2} \theta}{\left(\sec ^{2} \theta+\tan ^{2} \theta\right)^{2}} d \theta \\
=& \int \frac{d t}{\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)^{2}}, \text { where } t=\tan \theta
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{2} & =\int \frac{d t}{\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)^{2}}\\&=-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{t} d\left(\frac{1}{1+2 t^{2}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4 t\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)} d t\right.\\
&=-\frac{1}{4 t\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{4} \int\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}-\frac{2}{1+2 t^{2}}\right) d t \\
&=-\frac{1}{4 t\left(1+2 t^{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{4 t}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{2} t)+C \\
&=\frac{t}{2\left(2 t^{2}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{2} t)+C \\
&=\frac{\tan \theta}{2\left(2 \tan ^{2} \theta+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{2} \tan \theta)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Now let’s go further to $I_3$ by the substitution $\tan u=\sin \theta$.
$$\begin{aligned} \int \frac{\cos ^{3} \theta}{\left(1+\sin ^{2} \theta\right)^{3}} d \theta &=\int \frac{1-\tan ^{2} u}{\left(1+\tan ^{2} \theta\right)^{3}} \cdot \sec ^{2} u d u \\ &=\int \frac{1-\tan ^{2} u}{\sec ^{4} u} d u \\ &=\int\left(\cos ^{4} u-\sin ^{2} u \cos ^{2} u\right) d u \\ &=\int \cos ^{2} u\left(\cos ^{2} u-\sin ^{2} u\right) d u \\ &=\int \frac{1+\cos 2 u}{2} \cos 2 u d u \\ &=\frac{\sin 2 u}{4}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1+\cos 4 u}{2} d u \\ &=\frac{\sin u \cos u}{2}+\frac{1}{4} u+\frac{1}{16} \sin 4 u+C \\ &=\frac{\sin u \cos u}{2}+\frac{u}{4}+\frac{\sin u \cos u \cos 2 u}{4}+C \\ &=\frac{u}{4}+\frac{\sin u \cos u}{4}(2+\cos 2 u)+C \\ & =\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(\sin \theta)+\frac{\sin \theta}{4\left(1+\sin ^{2} \theta\right)}\left(2+\frac{1-\sin ^{2} \theta}{1+\sin ^{2} \theta}\right)+C\\& =\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(\sin \theta)+\frac{\sin \theta\left(\sin ^{2} \theta+3\right)}{(\cos 2 \theta-3)^{2}}+C\end{aligned}$$

:|D Wish you enjoy my solution!