# How to find $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1+2\cos(t)}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

The problem is
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1+2\cos(t)}.$$ I know it is equal to 
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2dz}{i(1+z)^2}$$
but I don't know how I should calculate the last integral.

Comment: Alternatively, we can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Comment: @Roze: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Does this integral exist?

Comment: Note that, $z=-1$ is on the path of integration which is the unit circle.

Comment: Instead of $$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2dz}{i(1+z)^2}$$ the complex integral should be $$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{i\left( z+\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\right) \left( z+\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) }.
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{i(1+z)^2}=\frac i{1+z}+C
$$

---

As suggested in a comment, the [Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) is often useful in integrals such as the original.
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(t)&=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\\
\cos(t)&=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\\
\mathrm{d}t&=\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Adjusted Hint:**

As pointed out by Américo Tavares,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+2\cos(t)}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+e^{it}+e^{-it}}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t}{e^{2it}+e^{it}+1}\\
&=\oint\frac{-i\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+z+1}\\
&=\oint\frac1{\sqrt3}\left(\frac1{z-\omega^2}-\frac1{z-\omega}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$
where $\omega=\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}$.

Since the sum of the residues at $\omega^2$ and $\omega$ is $0$, if we take a branch cut between $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, we can well-define
$$
f(z)=\frac1{\sqrt3}\log\left(\frac{z-\omega^2}{z-\omega}\right)
$$
over the rest of $\mathbb{C}$, and $f'(z)=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\left(\dfrac1{z-\omega^2}-\dfrac1{z-\omega}\right)$. $f$ works the same as $\dfrac{i}{1+z}$ in my previous hint.

Comment: The trigonometric integral becomes $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\limits_{|z|=1}\left( \frac{1}{1+2\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}
\right) \frac{1}{iz}dz &=&\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{i}\times 
\frac{1}{z^{2}+z+1}dz \\
&=&\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{i\left( z+\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\right) \left( z+\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) }
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
and not

$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2dz}{i(1+z)^2},$$ as computed by OP.

Comment: @AméricoTavares: thanks for noticing this. The corrected integral can be handled in a similar way to the incorrect one, as I have amended to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you write
$$
\begin{equation*}
z=e^{it}\qquad \left( 0\leq t\leq 2\pi \right), 
\end{equation*}
$$

since
$$
\begin{equation*}
\cos t=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2},\qquad dt=\frac{dz}{iz},
\end{equation*}
$$

the integral takes the form
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\limits_{|z|=1}\left( \frac{1}{1+2\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}
\right) \frac{1}{iz}dz &=&\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{i}\times 
\frac{1}{z^{2}+z+1}dz \\
&=&\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{i\left( z+\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\right) \left( z+\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) }
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
and not

$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{2dz}{i(1+z)^2}.$$

---

Since $\cos \frac{2\pi }{3}=\cos \frac{4\pi }{3}=-\frac{1}{2}$, hence $1+2\cos \frac{2\pi }{3}=1+\cos \frac{4\pi }{3}=0$, the given integral has singularities at $t\in\{\frac{2\pi, }{3},\frac{4\pi }{3}\}$. We thus split it as follows:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi }{3}}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos t}+\int_{\frac{2\pi }{3}}^{\frac{4\pi }{3}}\frac{dt}{1+2\cos t}+\int_{\frac{4\pi }{3}}^{2\pi }\frac{dt}{1+2\cos t}.
\end{equation*}
$$

Each integral is a divergent improper integral of the second kind. Using the [Weirstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)$^1$  $x=\tan \frac{t}{2}$, for instance the first integral becomes

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{1} &=&\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi }{3}}\frac{1}{1+2\cos t}dt,\qquad x=\tan \frac{t}{2} \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{2}{\left( 1+2\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)
\left( 1+x^{2}\right) }\,dx \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{2}{3-x^{2}}\,dx,\qquad x=\sqrt{3}u \\
&=&\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-u^{2}}\,du \\
&=&\left. \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\operatorname{arctanh}u\right\vert _{0}^{1}=\infty .
\end{eqnarray*} 
$$

--

$^1$ The Weierstrass substitution is a *universal standard substitution* to evaluate an integral of a rational fraction in $\sin t,\cos t$, i.e. a rational fraction of the form

$$R(\sin t,\cos t)=\frac{P(\sin t,\cos t)}{Q(\sin t,\cos t)},$$

where $P,Q$  are polynomials in $\sin t,\cos t$

$$
\begin{equation*}
\tan \frac{t }{2}=x,\qquad t =2\arctan x,\qquad dt =\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}dx
\end{equation*},
$$

which converts the integrand into a rational function in $x$. We know from trigonometry (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/377139/752)) that

$$\cos t =\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{t }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{
t}{2}}=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2},\qquad \sin t =\frac{2\tan \frac{t }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}
\frac{t }{2}}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: @Roze You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Open,$\cos(t)$ as $1-2\sin^2(t/2)$,

The denominator of your integral then becomes,$3-4\sin^2(t/2)$.
Multiply $\sec^2(t/2)$ in the Numerator and Denominator.
Your integrand  then becomes,$\frac{\sec^2(t/2)}{3\sec^2(t/2)-4\tan^2(t/2)}$
Substitute,$z=\tan(t/2)$
Your integrand now modifies to(ignoring constants),$\frac{1}{3-z^2}$,
which is of known form and can be resolved using numerous methods(one of them being partial fractions)

Comment: Ok,I just realized(after looking at the other answers) that the definite integral diverges,but you could nevertheless use the indefinite integral in cases where the limits imply convergence of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that, the original integral is an improper integral since the integrand has singularities in the interval of integration $[0,2\pi]$. Namely, $t=\frac{2}{3}\pi$ and $\frac{4}{3}\pi$. You can find these singularities by solving the equation

$$ 1 + 2\cos(t) = 0. $$

So, you should know how to handle this integral. Here is the value of the indefinite integral

$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt {3}}\,\,{\it \tanh^{-1}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\tan \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) \right) .$$

For the complex integral, you can see that you have a pole on the path of integration as I pointed out in my comment.